# Useful TortoiseHg extensions

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Guys, could you please describe TortoiseHg extensions which comes with the installation package? What do these do and which you use on the daily basis? What are more useful?

This is the list from TortoiseHg v1.1.5 for Windows.

```
[extensions]
; extensions shipped with Mercurial by default
;
;acl =
;bookmarks =
;bugzilla =
;children =
;churn =
; Warning: the color extension is not recommended for Windows
;color =
;convert =
;extdiff =
;fetch =
;gpg =
;graphlog = 
;hgcia =
;hgk =
;highlight = 
;interhg =
;keyword =
;mq =
;notify =
;pager =
;parentrevspec =
;patchbomb =
;progress =
;purge =
;rebase =
;record =
;schemes =
;transplant =
;win32mbcs =
;win32text =
;zeroconf =
; Extra extensions bundled with TortoiseHg
;fold =
;hgcr-gui =
;perfarce =
;hgeol =
;mercurial_keyring =
```

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CategoryBundledExtension

Comment: And which are most useful? Which do you use on the daily basis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My personal favorites:

```
graphlog    ASCII graph next to changesets to visualize branching.  
mq          Handle local changes as a series of patches that can be edited.  
purge       Mass delete of unrevisioned files (and ignored files with --all).  
rebase      transplant a branch onto a different changeset.  
transplant  Copy a changeset onto the local changeset.
```

Of these, I use `mq` and `purge` daily.

Answer (score 5):

After one year of experience I have gained my own must-have list of most useful mercurial extensions (using Windows and TortoiseHg). Will list in the order of importance.

1. mq (for history edition and rebase become enabled)
2. rebase (for changes movements around repo)
3. transplant (sometimes needed for precise control of changesets)
4. bookmarks (rarely needed to mark a head of a branch)

Answer (score 1):

the color extension made me curious so here is what the [docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ColorExtension) say for it:

> This extension modifies the status command to add color to its output to reflect file status, the qseries command to add color to reflect patch status (applied, unapplied, missing), and to diff-related commands to highlight additions, removals, diff headers, and trailing whitespace.
>
> Other effects in addition to color, like bold and underlined text, are also available. Effects are rendered with the ECMA-48 SGR control function (aka ANSI escape codes). This module also provides the render_text function, which can be used to add effects to any text.